# SharePoint Search managed property: Difference 'query' and 'search'

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property

I'm having a hard time understanding the functional difference between the managed property property 'query' and 'search'. Both seem to allow me to do KQL property restriction searches. Can someone explain the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from this article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/search-schema-overview

Searchable: Enables querying against the content of the managed property. The content of this managed property is included in the full-text index.

Example: If the property is "author", a simple query for "Smith" returns items that contain the word "Smith" and items whose author property contains "Smith".

Queryable: Enables querying against the specific managed property. The managed property name must be included in the query, either specified in the query itself or included in the query programmatically.

Example: If the managed property is "author", the query must contain "author:Smith".

Comment: I don't understand th difference between "items that contain the word Smith" and "items whose author property contains Smith".